# Best way to navigate between pages and handle back button in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

Hiii, My question is that, let assume that I have a signin page,The user can switch between the signin and signup pages, but what I want, is that when the user login or create a new account in the signup pages, all the history would be removed.
Or if it's not possible, what is the best way to handle those situations, to avoid that the user had login then when he clicks in the back button, he will find himself again in one of the two pages(signin or signout).
I am currently using React Router v4. And it will be cool if anyone could help me and also give me the best practices for this.
thank you.

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={SignIn} exact />
          <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
          <Route path="/main" component={ContainerSingleApp} />
          <Route component={Error} />
        </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Well, as a naive approach you can use the auth state. Somehow you update your state after signin and signup right? So, just check your state in those components and if there is auth redirect the user wherever you want.

Comment: thanks @devserkan, I have tought of this, but the problem is if you would do the signout, you have to check in every page, so I was wandering if is exists a best practice for this. Thank you very much

Comment: If a page needs to look for the auth state then you can't escape from this one. You should check it somehow. Via passing props or using a solution like Redux etc, but you should do it.

Comment: Iam allready using redux on my app thanks god lol. So there isn't another trick to do it :/ ! Thank you

Comment: If there is then I don't know :) Here is a very simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/yk519xy7px When you try to open /dashboard it kicks you to homepage again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the react-router-v4 [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) that explains redirects with special emphasis on auth? That is the method I have used in the past and it's worked really well.

The gist is that you create a `<PrivateRoute />` component that wraps react-router's `<Route />` component and basically will display the `Login` component if the user tries to navigate to a private route without being logged in.  Otherwise the user will be given the view for the route that they requested.

For example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/main" component={ContainerSingleApp} />
        <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And from the documentation:

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

To solve the problem of having the user press the back button you can swap out the redirect in the `PrivateRoute` component with your `Login` component.  That way you aren't actually doing a redirect to a route that points at your Login, you are simply rendering the Login in place of the private component that the user is trying to access.  Once the user is logged in, it will render the component that they are trying to see.  Since there is no `/login` route needed for this approach, you don't need to worry about the user browsing back to the login page unless they are actually not logged in.  See the changes in the code below:

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Login />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

The routes in the first coding example above demonstrate a setup where the landing page is not protected by authentication.

If you want your landing page to be a view that is protected with authentication (like your `/main` route that points at the `ContainerSingleApp` component) then you still wouldn't need to add the `Login` component as a route.  You could do something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={ContainerSingleApp} />
        <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Remember that in the `PrivateRoute` component it will display the login view automatically if the user isn't logged in.  If they are, it will render the passed-in component.

It's important to note that the url will never show something like `https://your-site.com/login`.  It will always show the route for the component the user is attempting to access.  The difference being that the component that it renders will depend on whether the user is authenticated... The `Login` component if not, and the `ContainerSingleApp` component (or whatever component that route points to) if logged in.

If you still want to create a route to the login page you can use a redirect:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={ContainerSingleApp} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={() => <Redirect to="/"/>}
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

See the [redirect documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect).  As for the `Signup` component... Just add logic in it that will redirect the user to another page if already logged in.  You can use a similar approach that you used with the `PrivateRoute` component.

Comment: thank you, I will try it out, but what if the user is logged, then press the back button, this is my mine question, I don't want the user go back to the Login page

Comment: And if the landing page is the signin page I wiil have <Route path="/" component={Signin}> ??

Comment: @G.Adnane Good question. I added more clarity to the answer.

Comment: @G.Adnane The short answer is no.  You don't ever need to create a route that points to the `Signin` component.

Comment: But steel we got one problem, when the user is not logged, I want him to be able to navigate between the signin and the signup and can also connect from the signup page, so I think I could wrap it also in a <PrivateRoute/>
And please, there isn't a way to change tue url dynamically, I want to displat the /signin ad /signup on the url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186207/discussion-between-maninacan-and-g-adnane).